# Create UIViewController xib file for my existing ViewController file in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have an existing View Controller file with a set of code. I want to create an interface builder file for the ViewController and link them. Right now i don't seem to find UIViewController option in the New file options as give here.
[image]

Can any body tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now Apple preferably recommend to use storyboard as its easy to use and handle view controllers but still if you want to create separate view controller Please follow these steps.

1- Create objective c file or swift as you like
2- Change the UIView class to UIViewController
3- Create xib file
4- [Add UIViewController object as shown in pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usGeK.png)
5- Select the controller go to the 'Show inspector identity' and set the controller custom class

Comment: This does not work for me in swift 4. I get a crash and the message of  "loaded the "myViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set."

Comment: Add the ControllerView outlet to view in nib file.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that I need to create an empty xib and then include the view controllers as needed. And then follow the instructions as suggested by kkRocks suggested url will link the existing view controller to the new xib.